# is that ok to submit an ios app to the app store without respecting apple autolayout standards?

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I have finished my ios app and I will submit it to the app store but I have a question before submitting. 
is that ok to submit my app without respecting apple autolayout standards : >= 20 constraint constant to the side of the device and >=8 constraint constant to the edge of another UI element. 
Thank you for your help !

Comment: Your app just looks okay on all iPhones and it should run fine on iPad in letterbox window. Thats all you need in respect of UI.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This sounds like you just have a different design than the usual Apple design.

There isn’t really a standard for exact design specs like this.

You will have no problem arising from these auto layout settings when submitting this app.

Comment: even if I submit the app with autolayout warnings apple will not complain about it ?

Comment: You don’t mention any warnings in your question. Apple will not reject your app for design differences. Nor will they reject for code warnings. If those warnings cause broken behaviour or crashes then they may reject it. There is no downside to just submitting it though. That way you will find out for certain.